# KendoUI nummerictextbox format currency Euro not working

Tags: textbox, format, kendo-ui

I use the KendoUI nummeric control like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(o => o.Price)
            .Culture("nl-NL")
            .Format("c")
            .Decimals(0)
            .Spinners(false)
            .Min(0)
            .Max(50000000)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "width: 300px;" }))
```

In the textarea i get this result: **$87,845.00**

I would like to have my result like this: **€ 87 845** or **87 845 €**

The strange part is that i set decimals to 0 and i get 2 digits after the .

Anyone ?

Currently i have a work around and i set the formtat to "0 €" and i get this **87845 €** 
(There is no space after 3 digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several questions:

- `Decimals` affect only edition mode. Saying `Decimals(1)` allows you to enter 1 decimal, saying `0`, does not allow you to enter decimals.
- For controlling the display once edited you should use `Format("c0")`
- About not getting the `€`, it seems to me that you are not including `js/cultures/kendo.culture.nl-NL.min.js` file, is that possible?

Comment: Why would the currency and the culture be related? What if I wanted Bitcoin? What If I wanted to show both an amount in euro an dollar, would I really have to specify the culture? Your answer is correct, but Kendo UI is so weird.